# Center an image vertically

Tags: css, image, css-position, center, vertical-alignment

I have developed a website for a gallery of images. Currently, each image is aligned to the top, I am wishing the image to be in the center of the DIV.

Here is my code:

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    top:5%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto  
}
```

Here is my website link too see it in action: http://www.canninginc.co.nz/canluciddream/screenshots.html

The last image is a good example. It is a small image, and I am wishing it to be placed vertically in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
.carousel .item {
        position:relative;
        height: 900px;
        background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }
```

and try this, very helpful [Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering In CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)